# How to use new pretraining model with different dataset in DIGITS (different labels)?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I want to use VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers as a pretrained model in digits but with different dataset. 
Do I need different label files? How can I upload this model and use it for my dataset?

for the VGG 16 layers I got

> ERROR: Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc6'; shape mismatch.
>   Source param shape is 1 1 4096 25088 (102760448); target param shape
>   is 4096 32768 (134217728). To learn this layer's parameters from
>   scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.

how can modify layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your labels are associated with your dataset in DIGITS - not your model. When you upload a pretrained VGG model, you'll probably need to rename your last inner product layer (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837047/2404152)) so that your model will work on N classes instead of 1000.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got "ERROR: Your deploy network is missing a Softmax layer! Read the documentation for custom networks and/or look at the standard networks for examples"

Comment: Well that's a different problem. Feel free to post another question either here on SO or on GitHub.