# Deploy network is missing a Softmax layer

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, softmax, nvidia-digits

I try to use pretrained model (VGG 19) to DIGITS but I got this error.

> ERROR: Your deploy network is missing a Softmax layer! Read the
>   documentation for custom networks and/or look at the standard networks
>   for examples

I try to test with my dataset which has only two classes.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811936/using-bvlc-googlenet-as-pretrained-model-in-digits-errors/39837047#39837047) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121099/how-to-use-new-pretraining-model-with-different-dataset-in-digits-different-lab) try to modify last layer but also I got error. How can I modify layers based on new dataset?

I try to modify the last layer and I got error

> ERROR: Layer 'softmax' references bottom 'fc8' at the TRAIN stage however this blob is not included at that stage. Please consider using an include directive to limit the scope of this layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having a problem because you're trying to upload a "train/val" network when you really need to be uploading an "all-in-one" network. Unfortunately, we don't document this very well. I've created [an RFE](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/1192) to remind us to improve the documentation.

Try to adjust the last layers in your network to look something like this: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0/digits/standard-networks/caffe/lenet.prototxt#L162-L184

For more information, [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/4458) is how I've proposed updating Caffe's example networks to all-in-one nets, and [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/pull/628) is how I updated the default DIGITS networks to be all-in-one nets.

Comment: Thanks but I got error when I change the last layer. "ERROR: Layer 'softmax' references bottom 'fc8' at the TRAIN stage however this blob is not included at that stage. Please consider using an include directive to limit the scope of this layer."    How can I change the last layer?

Comment: How can I change the last layer? How can I use "all-in-one"? The "all-in-one" related to Fine-tuning Models? for using VGG 19 layers how can I modify last layer in order to use in my dataset which has only two classes?

Comment: you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33773152/1714410) useful: how to convert "train" prototxt to "deploy" prototxt.

Comment: How can I create All in one network? DIGITS support all-in-one network?