# The training DIGITS for pretrained model with my data-set does not work properly.

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I try to use pre-trained model (VGG 16) to DIGITS for my dataset which has two classes. but I got wrongly training. (I change the name of last layers to fc8_new)
[image: does not connect to previous layers]
I uploaded `deploy.prototxt` and `VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers.caffemodel` and `synset_words.txt` successfully into DIGITS and tested with my data-set which has two classes. 
 [image: at the end of training]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You have problem with training or testing?

Comment: why there is not curve on your 2nd picture? What was the snapshot interval???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `deploy.prototxt` won't include any loss or accuracy layers. I'm not really sure what Caffe will do when you try to train a network without any loss layers.

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144046/2404152), you're going to need to create an "all-in-one" network which includes all the layers needed for training, validation and deployment in a single network. @Shai linked to [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773152/2404152) as well.

As explained [on our GitHub README](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/digits-4.0#usage-questions), we prefer to answer these questions on our [user group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/digits-users) instead of here on SO.