# I am getting error while finetuning fcn-alexnet for my single-channel dataset

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe, nvidia-digits

I am running fcn-alexnet for semantic segmentation, I downloaded the pretrained model. Since my data is single channel,it is showing an error:

```
 ERROR: Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv1'; shape mismatch. Source param shape is 96 3 11 11 (34848); target param shape is 96 1 11 11 (11616). To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.
```

Could someone please guide me?
The shape is as follows:

```
Feature shape (1, 256, 256)
Label shape (1, 256, 256)
```

Comment: you can't load a blob partially without changing caffe code. As the error already suggests you should rename the layer. and train.

Answer (score 0):

If you only needed to retrain the last layer, you could just rename it (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837047/2404152).

In your case, the problem is that `96x3x11x11` != `96x1x11x11`. You're trying to apply a pretrained model that was intended for color images to a grayscale dataset (as you already discovered). The simplest fix is to just train on color images as well. One way to do this would be to add a `Tile` layer to copy the input three times.

Obviously, that wouldn't be very efficient. But that's the only way I can think of to use the pretrained model on grayscale data.

Comment: ThanksHow can I apply tile layer? after data layer and bottom and top layer what should be? IS this correct? 
layers {
   name: "tl"
   type: "Tile"
   bottom: "data"
   top: "data"
   tiling_param {
     tile_dim: 3
   }
}

Comment: I think that's about right. But you can't do it in-place since the shape changes. So call the output "data_tiled" or something like that.